# Obtaining $\mathbb CP^n$ as an identification space of $D^{2n}.$

Tags: algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces, projective-space

> Prove that $\mathbb C P^n$ is the identification space $D^{2n}/\sim$ where $x \sim y$ if either $x = y$ or $q(x) = q(y),$ where $q$ is the usual quotient map $S^{2n+1} \xrightarrow {q} \mathbb CP^n.$

**My Attempt** $:$ There is an obvious natural embedding $\iota : D^{2n} \longrightarrow S^{2n+1}$ given by $$(z_1,\cdots,z_n) \longmapsto \left (z_1,\cdots,z_n,\sqrt {1 - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} |z_i|^2} \right ).$$ So the image of $D^{2n}$ under this embedding is the upper hemisphere of $S^{2n+1}.$ Since the quotient map is the $S^1$ action on $S^{2n+1}$ and the action of $S^1$ identifies the all the points in $S^{2n+1}$ which are $S^1$ multiples it identifies antipodal points of $S^{2n+1}$ in particular. So if we restrict $q$ to the upper hemisphere it will still be an onto continuous map. So by universal property of quotient topology it will induce a bijective continuous map $\widetilde {q} : D^{2n}/\sim \longrightarrow \mathbb C P^n,$ where $D^{2n}/\sim$ is the quotient space consisting of fibres of $q \big \rvert_{D^{2n}},$ where $D^{2n}$ is viewed as the upper hemisphere of $S^{2n+1}$ by means of the embedding $\iota.$ Now we use the well-known trick. The domain of $\widetilde {q}$ is compact and the range is Hausdorff and hence $\widetilde {q}$ is a homeomorphism.

Is my above reasoning correct? Can anyone kindly check it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof has a flaw.

Let us first have a look at the equivalence relation on $D^{2n}$. This is not defined very accurately. Writing $q(x) = q(y)$ requires an explanation which map $q$ is. I think we must interpret it as $q : S^{2n-1} = \partial D^{2n} \to \mathbb CP^{n-1}$ and not as $q : S^{2n+1} \to \mathbb CP^{n}$. The second interpretation would require a canonical identification of points $\xi  \in D^{2n}$ with points $\xi' \in S^{2n+1}$. This can be done via your embedding $\iota : D^{2n} \to S^{2n+1}$; then we can define $x \sim y$ if $q(\iota(x)) = q(\iota(y))$. But doing so would make it obsolete to define $x \sim y$ if **either** $x = y$ **or** $q(x) = q(y)$. This is why we need to use $q : S^{2n-1} \to \mathbb CP^{n-1}$; this map can only be applied to *boundary points* of $D^{2n}$ which explains the $x = y$ part in  the definition of $x \sim y$.

For the sake of notational transparency let us write $q_m : S^{2m+1} \to CP^{m}$ for the quotient map. Let us also recall what the action of $S^1$ on $S^{2m+1}$ looks like. We have $S^{2m+1} = \{ (z_1,\ldots,z_{m+1}) \in \mathbb C^{m+1} \mid \sum_{i=1}^{m+1} \lvert z_i \rvert^2 = 1 \}$ and for $\lambda \in S^1$ we have $\lambda (z_1,\ldots,z_{m+1}) = (\lambda z_1,\ldots,\lambda z_{m+1})$.

Claim. $x \sim y$ (in the sense $x = y$ or $q_{n-1}(x) = q_{n-1}(y)$) if and only if $q_n(\iota(x)) = q_n(\iota(y))$.

Proof. We consider $ x= (u_1,\ldots,u_n) \in S^{2n-1}$ and  $y= (v_1,\ldots,v_n) \in S^{2n-1}$.

Let $x \sim y$. If $x=y$, then trivially $q_n(\iota(x)) = q_n(\iota(y))$. So assume that $q_{n-1}(x) = q_{n-1}(y)$. This means that $x,y \in S^{2n-1}$ and $(\lambda u_1,\ldots,\lambda u_n) = (v_1,\ldots, v_n)$ for some $\lambda \in S^1$. But $x,y \in S^{2n-1}$ implies that $\iota(x)  = (u_1,\ldots,u_n,0)$ and $\iota(y)  = (v_1,\ldots,v_n,0)$. This gives us
$$\lambda \iota(x)  = \left(\lambda u_1,\ldots,\lambda u_n, 0 \right ) = \left(v_1,\ldots,v_n, 0 \right ) = \iota(y)$$
and therefore $q_n(\iota(x)) = q_n(\iota(y))$.

Conversely, let $q_n(\iota(x)) = q_n(\iota(y))$ which means that $\lambda \iota(x) =  \iota(y)$ for some $\lambda \in S^1$, i.e.  $\lambda x =  y$ and
$$\lambda \cdot \sqrt {1 - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} |u_i|^2} = \sqrt {1 - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} |v_i|^2} .$$
Since the square roots are real and nonnegative, this is only possible if $\lambda = 1$ or $\sqrt {1 - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} |u_i|^2} = \sqrt {1 - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} |v_i|^2} = 0$. In the first case we have $\iota(x) =  \iota(y)$, thus $x = y$. In the second case we have $x,y \in S^{2n-1}$ and $\lambda x = y$ which means $q_{n-1}(x) = q_{n-1}(y)$.

Now you have an error: The image of $D^{2n}$ under $\iota$ is **not** the upper hemisphere of $S^{2n+1}$. In fact, the upper hemisphere of $S^{2n+1}$ is a copy of $D^{2n+1}$. But what we can say is that
$$\iota(D^{2n}) =  \bar S^{2n+1} = \{ (z_1,\ldots,z_{n+1}) \in S^{2n+1} \mid z_{n+1} \text{ is real and nonnegative} \} .$$
The inclusion $\iota(D^{2n}) \subset \bar S^{2n+1}$ is obvious. Conversely, if $(z_1,\ldots,z_{n+1}) \in \bar S^{2n+1}$, then $z_{n+1} = \lvert z_{n+1} \rvert = \sqrt{1 - \sum_{i=1}^n \lvert z_i \rvert^2}$, thus $(z_1,\ldots,z_{n+1}) = \iota((z_1,\ldots,z_n))$.

The good news is that nevertheless $q_n(\iota(D^{2n}) = \mathbb CP^{n}$. In fact, consider $\xi = (z_1,\ldots, z_{n+1}) \in S^{2n+1}$. If $z_{n+1} = 0$, then $x= (z_1,\ldots, z_n) \in S^{2n-1}$ and $\xi = \iota(x)$. If $z_{n+1} \ne 0$, then $\lambda = \frac{\overline{z_{n+1}}}{\lvert z_{n+1}\rvert} \in S^1$ and $\lambda \xi = (z'_1,\ldots,z'_n, \lvert z_{n+1} \rvert)$. We conclude that $\lambda \xi = \iota(x)$ with $x = (z'_1,\ldots,z'_n) \in D^{2n}$. Thus in both case $q_n(\xi) = q_n(\iota(x)) \in q_n(\iota(D^{2n})$.

From that point your arguments correctly apply.

Let us remark that the alternative representation $\mathbb CP^{n} = D^{2n}/\sim$ means nothing else than that $\mathbb CP^{n}$ is obtained from $\mathbb CP^{n-1}$ by attaching a $2n$-cell $D^{2n}$ via $q_{n-1} : S^{2n-1} \to CP^{n-1}$.

Comment: What I observed is that the last coordinate of the image of $\iota$ is a real number and hence if we change the coordinate system into reals then the last coordinate is always zero and hence the image lies on the equator $S^{2n}.$ I think that the image of $\iota$ is precisely the the equator. Isn't it so? Can we say that $q \big \rvert_{S^{2n}}$ is also $\mathbb C P^n\ $?

Comment: @Phibetakappa The image of $\iota$ is not the equator (because $D^{2n} \not\approx S^{2n}$). It is the upper hemisphere of the equatorial $S^{2n}$; the last coordinate $z_{n+1}$ is real **and nonnegative**. But of course $\mathbb CP^n$ is a quotient space of $S^{2n}$. In fact it is a quotient space of any compact $X \subset S^{2n+1}$ such that $q(X) =  \mathbb CP^n$. What is the important point in considering $D^{2n}/\sim$ is explained in the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Since the action of $S^1$ identifies antipodal points in particular it follows that the image of the upper hemisphere of the equatorial $S^{2n}$ is $\mathbb C P^n,$ which I need in this case.

Comment: But what I know is that $\mathbb C P^n$ is the quotient of $S^{2n+1},$ namely $\mathbb C P^n = S^{2n+1}/ S^1.$ Isn't it so? Then how do I conclude that the image of the upper hemisphere  of the equatorial $S^{2n}$ is $\mathbb C P^n\ $?

Comment: @Phibetakappa Corrrect.

Comment: Respected @Paul Frost can you please address my last comment? What I know is that $\mathbb C P^n = S^{2n +1}/S^1.$ I don't know how to write $\mathbb C P^n$ as a quotient of $S^{2n}.$

Comment: @Phibetakappa Let $X$ be any compact subset of $S^{2n+1}$ such that $q(X) = \mathbb CP^n$. An example is $X = S^{2n}$. On $X$ define $x \sim y$ if $q(x) = q(y)$, that is, if $\lambda x =  y$ for some $\lambda \in S^1$. It may of course happen that $X$ does not contain the full orbit of certain $x \in X$, but that is irrelevant. Then clearly $q  \mid_X$ induces a continuous bijection $\bar q  : X /\sim \to \mathbb CP^n$. This map is a homeomorphism because $ X /\sim$ is compact.

Comment: In this case aren't you assuming that $q(S^{2n}) = \mathbb C P^n\ $? What you wrote in the last paragraph of your answer is expression of $\mathbb C P^n$ as an adjunction space $\mathbb C P^{n-1} \cup_{q_{n-1}} D^{2n}$ by means of a pushout.

Comment: @Phibetakappa In my answer I proved that $q(\iota(D^{2n})) = \mathbb CP^n$.  But $\iota(D^{2n}) \subset S^{2n}$, thus $q(S^{2n}) = \mathbb CP^n$. Concerning the pushout you are right.

Comment: Yeah I get your point now. Sorry for questioning you for so long. It is my failure that I have not been able to extract the essential cream from your detailed and thorough nectar discussion.

Comment: @Phibetakappa Don't worry. There is no reason to be sorry.